# How to set port for pyspark jupyter notebook?

Tags: bash, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am starting a pyspark jupyter notebook with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddres=...
echo "Start notebook server at IP address $ipaddress"

function snotebook ()
{
#Spark path (based on your computer)
SPARK_PATH=/home/.../software/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

# For python 3 users, you have to add the line below or you will get an error
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3

$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[10]
}

snotebook --no-browser --ip $ipaddress --certfile=/home/.../local/mycert.pem --keyfile /home/.../local/mykey.key
```

I wonder how to set the port. Is there an environment variable that I can set? I would like to determine the port before the notebook starts.  I tried `--port 7999`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Spark UI ports, in the `spark-env.sh`, it lists these two environment variables that you can overwrite, or set in that file

```
# - SPARK_MASTER_PORT / SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT, to use non-default ports for the master
# - SPARK_WORKER_PORT / SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT, to use non-default ports for the worker
```

I'm not sure the Jupyter values or if PySpark even passes them through, but if `jupyter notebook --port` works on its own, then I would try

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port=7999"
```

If you want to pass all the argument from `snotebook` into the variable, then you need

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook $@"
```