# How do I start pyspark with Jupyter options inline?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run `pyspark` with `Jupyter Lab` options (inline) as follows.

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter" PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --NotebookApp.notebook_dir='/' --NotebookApp.port=4444" $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
```

This approach inspired by the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html). However, when the command is executed, `notebooks` directory is served from `/root` and the port is still `8888`.

I also wrapped the execution in a `.sh` (shell) file as [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915274/how-do-i-run-pyspark-with-jupyter-notebook).

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --NotebookApp.notebook_dir='/' --NotebookApp.port=4444"

pyspark "$@"
```

But this attempt to override the notebook directory and port also does not work. I have checked to make sure that `/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` does not exists.

Any ideas on what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754061/how-to-set-port-for-pyspark-jupyter-notebook) and had `hard-coded` the environment variables in `spark-env.sh`. After removing those variables, everything works.